# $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+rx} + \sqrt {a+(r-1)x}}$

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions

Find the value of $$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+rx} + \sqrt {a+(r-1)x}}$$

Comment: Square covers the whole bracket part

Comment: You use way too many brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: rationalise the denominator , and see what you get when you write done a few terms of this series.

Comment: We get $$\sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{(\sqrt(a+rx) )-(\sqrt(a+(r-1)x))}{(x) }$$

Comment: Yep ,now write down a few terms of this series. Some terms could be cancelled.

Comment: Oh yes they are cancelling out

Comment: Thanks. I got then ans which is by the way $$\frac{(n)}{\sqrt( a+nx)+(\sqrt a) }$$

Comment: No problem , that’s it yeah